# Como definir o valor de uma variavel do css pelo java Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Quero definir a css progress via java script, fazendo com que ela se altere com um valor que eu colocar no input do Html. deem uma olhada:

HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HPCSS.css"> 
</head>

<div class="teste"></div>
<input id="vida" onchange="update()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="HPJS.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.teste{
 --progess:2000;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 display: flex
}
.teste::before{
content: "";
width: calc(var(--progess)*1%);
background-color: red
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function update(){
var vida= document.getElementById("vida")
var value= vida.value
}
```

Já consegui passaro valor do input pro JS, agora quero saber como definir esse valor como valor da variável progress no CSS
Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeceria

Comment: use a propriedade style: `document.querySelector(".teste").style["progress"] = valor;`

Comment: Não deu certo não

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty), que altera uma propriedade dentro de um bloco de estilo CSS:

```js
function update(){
   var vida= document.getElementById("vida")
   var value= vida.value
   document.querySelector(".teste").style.setProperty('--progess', value);
}
```

```css
.teste{
 --progess:5;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 display: flex
}
.teste::before{
content: "";
width: calc(var(--progess)*1%);
background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="teste"></div>
<input id="vida" onchange="update()">
```

Comment: DEU CERTO CARA OBRIGADO!!!